# IBM AS400 - Call a program perodically (over IEFFECT)

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there! 
I'm searching for a way to call a RPG/400 Program (via IEFFECT) once a week.

I already found a solution for searching every week for a spool file to work with (convert to pdf & send it via email). But I can't find a way to actually call a program -> get the spool -> convert it -> send it.

I mentioned IEFFECT since we use this software

Comment: Why not just use the job scheduler? `WRKJOBSCDE`

Comment: Seems the topic has nothing to do with RPG programming, and instead with how to use a product\application named IEFFECT to effect a [weekly] CALL to a program; i.e. that the PGM used is created as the HLL RPG, is immaterial.?  If so, then perhaps add ibm-midrange tag and remove the rpg tag.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: i tried using the `WRKJOBSCDE` command. i was able to create a job scheduling with `USER` *myName* and `MSGQ` **USRPRF* but i got no response (there was no spoolfile in my OUTQ)

Comment: Did the job execute successfully? Is there a job log? use `WRKJOB` with the job name specified in `WRKJOBSCDE` to see if there is any output from the job on your system. or use option 8 on `WRKJOBACDE` to see the last invocation. What is the next schedule date? Did you try option 10 just to make sure the job submission works?

Comment: If you give us more information, we can better help diagnose the problem. As it is, all I know is you added a job schedule entry, and have no output on your spool file. I don't even know if the program ran. The command that was scheduled, job logs, message id's, and maybe even some code would help. To force the job log to persist, you could set the `LOG` parameter in the associated job description to `4 0 *SECLVL`. If you are calling a CL program, you could also add `LOGCLPGM(*YES)`.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: with `WRKJOB` -> 10 there is a entry that says that the programm was called (*..CALL PGM(MYLIB/PGM019R)* - it's rpg/400)

Comment: the programm was called as scheduled (i set the timer to the current date with a `FRQ`of **WEEKLY* and for testing, i set the `SCDTIME` manually

Comment: the rpg program itself goes throug a database, collects some data and prints it out on a printerfile (`QSYSPRT`)

Comment: when the job is scheduled there comes a message (from the `MSGQ`) that tells me that the *Job 4711/MYNAME/JOBNAME* has been given to the scheduling entry *JOBNAME* with number 000086.

Comment: Then this is not a problem with the job scheduler, but maybe a problem with the program or job description (library list). If you have the job output the job log on successful completion, you should be able to see the library list it was submitted with.

Comment: @radinator Re WRKJOB Option-10=DspJobLog, output, as-described in a prior comment, Note:  From "Display Job Log - Help":
> The Display Job Log display shows you the commands processed by the
> job and the messages returned from running those commands. 
> If you are displaying a batch job, you can see commands that are   
still to be processed (identified by "..").
If the submitted job remains awaiting that request to be processed, the job may be on a job queue that is held or ???

Comment: Ok i found a mistake: the job is running and blocking the qbatch cause of a error (implicitly opening a file CPF4101)